# GROUPING BY DAY

Tags: oracle

I have a table, MSGCOUNT, that looks like the following:

```
SERVER  CHANNEL  VALUE  VARIABLE      VARNAME      DATES      TIME
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1       A        133    MessageCount  MSG_COUNT_A 12-NOV-18  10:16:56
1       A        129    MessageCount  MSG_COUNT_A 12-NOV-18  10:13:26
1       A        120    MessageCount  MSG_COUNT_A 12-NOV-18  10:00:55 
2       B        210    MessageCount  MSG_COUNT_B 12-NOV-18  21:42:45 
2       B        200    MessageCount  MSG_COUNT_B 12-NOV-18  21:41:25
2       B        195    MessageCount  MSG_COUNT_B 12-NOV-18  21:41:19
```

I want to be able to get a count of the total messages coming in for the day.

The result from the query will look like:

```
SERVER  CHANNEL  VALUE  VARIABLE      VARNAME      DATE      
----------------------------------------------------------
1       A        13    MessageCount  MSG_COUNT_A 12-NOV-18
2       B        15    MessageCount  MSG_COUNT_B 12-NOV-18
```

I have tried to use various functions, analytical and otherwise, but the following is the latest attempt:

```
select server, channel, value, variable, varname, date
from 
    (
      select time_interval as start_interval,
             time_interval as end_interval,
             round(MSG, 2) total_msg_recv,
             channel,
             server
      from
          (
            select substr(DATES, 1,9),
                   round(VALUE,2) MSG,
                   channel,
                   server
            from MSGCOUNT 
          )
    )
group by date, server, channel
order by date
```

This produces the following result (which is wrong):

```
SERVER CHANNEL VALUE VARIABLE     VARNAME       DATE
-----------------------------------------------------
1      A       133   MessageCount  MSG_COUNT_A  12-NOV-18
2      B       210   MessageCount  MSG_COUNT_B  12-NOV-18
```

Thanks

Comment: You want one result row per date, server, and channel? But you are displaying variable and varname in your results? Which would you display in case of different ones per date, server, and channel?

Comment: How and when are these rows inserted, and how is the value for each row determined? I'm wondering if you *might* need to compare the last value from one day with the last value from the previous day, rather than the first from today, if they're different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't a simple *subtraction* do the job?

```
SQL> with msgcount(server, channel, value, dates) as
  2    (select 1, 'a', 133, date '2018-11-12' from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'a', 129, date '2018-11-12' from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'a', 120, date '2018-11-12' from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 2, 'b', 210, date '2018-11-12' from dual union all
  7     select 2, 'b', 200, date '2018-11-12' from dual union all
  8     select 2, 'b', 195, date '2018-11-12' from dual
  9    )
 10  select server, channel, max(value) - min(value) diff, dates
 11  from msgcount
 12  group by server, channel, dates
 13  order by server;

    SERVER C       DIFF DATES
---------- - ---------- ----------
         1 a         13 12.11.2018
         2 b         15 12.11.2018

SQL>
```

It is unclear what `DATES` and `TIME` is/are (which datatype); in my opinion, it should be a single column of the `DATE` datatype. If so, you should `TRUNC`ate it (e.g. `TRUNC(DATES)`) and remove time component as it doesn't really matter here.

If you provide some more info, that query might be changed, but the general idea should still be OK.

Comment: I only used the code from line 10-13 and that instantly solved the requirement. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Of course, you used lines 10 onwards; previous lines (so called a "CTE", common table expression) are used as data source (as you didn't provide create table and insert into statements). Using CTE is a simple way to get test data, without actually creating any tables.

Comment: Ahh understood. If I wanted to group this by week, month, or even by an increment of an hour does this same style apply?

Comment: If it was by, for example, month, you'd truncate date value to month (`trunc(dates, 'mm')`) and use it in query. The principle is the same, more or less - you'd just change *what* you want to return.

Comment: Thank you. I will use this advice. Cheers

Comment: Sure; feel free to test it, you'll see how it behaves.